# Where is the convention to mark a symbol with `<symbol>' in comments comes from?

Tags: emacs, elisp, manpage

I see this both in man page and in emacs lisp doc string, it looks like a convention; is there a formal document about that?

what contexts should I follow this rule?

Comment: **How to quote symbols in a documentation string?**:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/9881/2287

Answer (score 0):

@lawlist has answered wrt where you can find the doc about this.

The reason for this convention is that it allows the code that composes a help buffer to recognize things for what they are: variables, functions, macros, keys, etc., and put links on them to take you to other help buffers.  Without the convention it is much more problematic trying to determine whether `foo` refers to variable `foo`, function `foo` etc.